# Could this novel algorithm be qualified to be published in Nature or Science

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I recently designed an algorithm for single-source shortest paths in graph structures, which can limit the number of edges as Bellman-Ford while approaching the performance of SPFA. Of course, it also supports negative weights and helps check the negative weight cycle.

The runtime ratio is `SPFA : Mine : Bellman-Ford = 5 : 11 : 90` in the python test case. Since the algorithms Bellman-Ford and SPFA are basic and widely used, I want to know whether this algorithm is qualified to be published in Nature or Science or not?

The principle uses two swapped and scrolling queues of relaxed vertices and two arrays of vertice weights inspired by Bellman-Ford and SPFA. You wouldn't get my point if you are not familiar with Bellman-Ford and SPFA. I would certainly explain the detailed principle in the paper but not here because it takes pictures and long words.

For example, AB = 2, AC = 1, CD =1, BD = 2

```
A
⬇️ ↘️
C   B
⬇️ ↙️
D
```

```
A B C D
-------
0 ∞ ∞ ∞
  2 1 
      2
```

In the last table at vertice D, its `2` is got from 4(BD) first, and changed to 2(CD) next. Besides, each row index represents the edge number of the path.

Python code:

```
from collections import deque
import time
import random

class Edge:
    def __init__(self, from_vertex, to_vertex, weight):
        self.from_vertex = from_vertex
        self.to_vertex = to_vertex
        self.weight = weight

class MyQueue:
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.vertices = deque()
        self.statuses = [False] * count

    def __contains__(self, i):
        return self.statuses[i]

    def offer(self, i):
        self.statuses[i] = True
        self.vertices.append(i)

    def poll(self):
        if self.vertices:
            res = self.vertices.popleft()
            self.statuses[res] = False
            return res
        return None

    def any(self):
        return bool(self.vertices)

    def none(self):
        return not self.vertices

def mine(edges, n, source_vertex, k):
    current = [float('inf')] * n
    following = [float('inf')] * n

    current_level_queue = MyQueue(n)
    next_level_queue = MyQueue(n)

    current_level_queue.offer(source_vertex)
    current[source_vertex] = 0
    following[source_vertex] = 0
    round = 0

    while True:
        from_vertex = current_level_queue.poll()
        if from_vertex is None:
            continue

        for edge in edges[from_vertex]:
            new_dist = current[edge.from_vertex] + edge.weight
            if new_dist >= following[edge.to_vertex]:
                continue

            following[edge.to_vertex] = new_dist
            if edge.to_vertex not in next_level_queue:
                next_level_queue.offer(edge.to_vertex)

        if current_level_queue.any(): continue

        if next_level_queue.none(): break

        round += 1

        if round == n:
            raise ValueError("Graph contains a negative weight cycle.")

        if round == k: break

        tmp = current_level_queue
        current_level_queue = next_level_queue
        next_level_queue = tmp

        current = following.copy()

    return following

def bellman_ford_with_limited_edges(edges, n, src, k):
    current = [float('inf')] * n
    current[src] = 0
    following = [float('inf')] * n

    for i in range(k):
        following[src] = 0
        is_updated = False

        for edge in edges:
            if current[edge.from_vertex] < float('inf') and following[edge.to_vertex] > current[edge.from_vertex] + edge.weight:
                following[edge.to_vertex] = current[edge.from_vertex] + edge.weight
                is_updated = True

        if not is_updated: break

        assert i != n, "Graph contains a negative weight cycle"

        current = following.copy()

    return following


def spfa(edges, vertices_count, source_vertex):
    weights = [float('inf')] * vertices_count
    in_queue = [False] * vertices_count
    queue = deque()

    weights[source_vertex] = 0
    queue.append(source_vertex)
    in_queue[source_vertex] = True

    while queue:
        u = queue.popleft()
        in_queue[u] = False

        for edge in edges[u]:
            new_dist = weights[u] + edge.weight
            if new_dist >= weights[edge.to_vertex]:
                continue
            weights[edge.to_vertex] = new_dist

            if in_queue[edge.to_vertex]:
                continue
            queue.append(edge.to_vertex)
            in_queue[edge.to_vertex] = True

    return weights


edges = []

vertex_count = 4000

for i in range(vertex_count):
    for j in range(i + 1, min(i + 100, vertex_count)):
        weight = random.randint(1, 100)
        edges.append(Edge(i, j, weight))
        edges.append(Edge(j, i, weight))

grouped_edges = [deque() for _ in range(vertex_count)]
for edge in edges:
    grouped_edges[edge.from_vertex].append(edge)

src = vertex_count // 2

print("Whether my my result equals to Bellman-Ford:")
myRet = mine(grouped_edges, vertex_count, src, 20)
bellman_ford_ret = bellman_ford_with_limited_edges(edges, vertex_count, src, 20)
print("When edge number is limited to {}: {}".format(20, myRet == bellman_ford_ret))

myRet = mine(grouped_edges, vertex_count, src, 30)
bellman_ford_ret = bellman_ford_with_limited_edges(edges, vertex_count, src, 30)
print("When edge number is limited to {}: {}".format(30, myRet == bellman_ford_ret))

myRet = mine(grouped_edges, vertex_count, src, vertex_count)
bellman_ford_ret = bellman_ford_with_limited_edges(edges, vertex_count, src, vertex_count)
print("When edge number is unlimited: {}".format(myRet == bellman_ford_ret))

print("\nRuntime ratio of unlimited edges:")

start_time = time.time()
mine(grouped_edges, vertex_count, src, vertex_count - 1)
end_time = time.time()

print("Mine: {:.2f} seconds".format(end_time - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
bellman_ford_with_limited_edges(edges, vertex_count, src, vertex_count - 1)
end_time = time.time()

print("Bellman-Ford: {:.2f} seconds".format(end_time - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
spfa(grouped_edges, vertex_count, src)
end_time = time.time()

print("SPFA: {:.2f} seconds".format(end_time - start_time))
```

Kotlin code

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.math.min
import kotlin.time.measureTime

data class Edge(val from: Int, val to: Int, val weight: Int)

fun bellmanFordWithLimitedEdges(edges: List<Edge>, n: Int, src: Int, isWarmUp: Boolean, k: Int): IntArray {
    var current = IntArray(n){ Int.MAX_VALUE }
    current[src] = 0
    val next = IntArray(n){ Int.MAX_VALUE }

    for (i in 0..< k) {
        next[src] = 0
        var isUpdated = false

        for ((from, to, dist) in edges) {
            if (current[from] < Int.MAX_VALUE && next[to] > current[from] + dist) {
                next[to] = current[from] + dist
                isUpdated = true
            }
        }

        if (!isUpdated) {
            if (!isWarmUp) println(i)
            break
        }
        require(i != n){
            "Graph has a negative weight cycle!"
        }

        current = next.clone()
    }
    return next
}

fun spfa(edges: List<List<Edge>>, verticesCount: Int, sourceVertex: Int): IntArray {
    val distances = IntArray(verticesCount) { Int.MAX_VALUE }
    val inQueue = BooleanArray(verticesCount) { false }
    val queue: Queue<Int> = LinkedList()

    distances[sourceVertex] = 0
    queue.offer(sourceVertex)
    inQueue[sourceVertex] = true

    while (queue.any()) {
        val u = queue.poll()
        inQueue[u] = false

        for ((_, to, weight) in edges[u]) {
            val newDist = distances[u] + weight
            if (newDist >= distances[to]) continue
            distances[to] = newDist

            if (inQueue[to]) continue
            queue.offer(to)
            inQueue[to] = true
        }
    }
    return distances
}

class MyQueue(count: Int){
    private val vertices = LinkedList<Int>()
    private val statuses = BooleanArray(count)

    operator fun contains(i: Int): Boolean = statuses[i]

    fun offer(i: Int){
        statuses[i] = true
        vertices += i
    }

    fun poll(): Int {
        val res = vertices.poll()
        statuses[res] = false
        return res
    }

    fun any(): Boolean = vertices.any()
    fun none(): Boolean = vertices.none()
}

fun myImpl(edges: List<List<Edge>>, verticesCount: Int, sourceVertex: Int, isWarmUp: Boolean, k: Int): IntArray {
    var currentLevelVerticeInfo = IntArray(verticesCount){ Int.MAX_VALUE }
    val nextLevelVerticeInfo = IntArray(verticesCount){ Int.MAX_VALUE }

    var currentLevelQueue = MyQueue(verticesCount)
    var nextLevelQueue = MyQueue(verticesCount)

    currentLevelQueue.offer(sourceVertex)
    currentLevelVerticeInfo[sourceVertex] = 0
    nextLevelVerticeInfo[sourceVertex] = 0
    var round = 0

    while (true) {
        val from = currentLevelQueue.poll()

        for ((_, to, weight) in edges[from]) {
            val newDist = currentLevelVerticeInfo[from] + weight
            if (newDist >= nextLevelVerticeInfo[to]) continue

            nextLevelVerticeInfo[to] = newDist

            if (to !in nextLevelQueue)
                nextLevelQueue.offer(to)
        }

        when{
            currentLevelQueue.any() -> continue

            nextLevelQueue.none() -> break

            ++round == verticesCount -> error("Graph contains a negative weight cycle.")

            round == k -> break

            else -> {
                currentLevelQueue = nextLevelQueue.also { nextLevelQueue = currentLevelQueue }
                currentLevelVerticeInfo = nextLevelVerticeInfo.clone()
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isWarmUp) println(round)
    return nextLevelVerticeInfo
}

fun main() {
    val edges = mutableListOf<Edge>()

    val vertexCount = 4000

    for (i in 0..< vertexCount) {
        for (j in i+1..< min(i+100, vertexCount)) {
            val weight = (1..100).random()
            edges += Edge(i, j, weight)
            edges += Edge(j, i, weight)
        }
    }

    val groupedEdges = MutableList(vertexCount){ LinkedList<Edge>() }
    edges.forEach {
        groupedEdges[it.from] += it
    }

    val src = vertexCount / 2

    check(
        bellmanFordWithLimitedEdges(edges, vertexCount, src, true, 20).toList() ==
                myImpl(groupedEdges, vertexCount, src, true, 20).toList()
    )

    check(bellmanFordWithLimitedEdges(edges, vertexCount, src, true, vertexCount).toList() ==
            myImpl(groupedEdges, vertexCount, src, true, vertexCount).toList()
    )

    // warm up
    repeat(5){
        bellmanFordWithLimitedEdges(edges, vertexCount, src, true, vertexCount)
        spfa(groupedEdges, vertexCount, src)
        myImpl(groupedEdges, vertexCount, src, true, vertexCount - 1)
        measureTime {  }
    }

    measureTime {
        bellmanFordWithLimitedEdges(edges, vertexCount, src, false, vertexCount)
    }
    .let{ println("${::bellmanFordWithLimitedEdges.name}: $it") }

    measureTime {
        spfa(groupedEdges, vertexCount, src)
    }
    .let{ println("spfa: $it") }

    measureTime {
        myImpl(groupedEdges, vertexCount, src, false, vertexCount - 1)
    }
    .let{ println("myImpl: $it") }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you write it up, prove its correctness and running time, state explicitly the dataset you used for your experiment, as well as your assumptions about the dataset.

Then upload it to Arxiv. I would personally skip Nature and Science and rather aim at an actual algorithms journal. Perhaps even better is a conference where you can present the results first and discuss with peers.

Look at SEA (Symposium for Experimental Algorithms) or ALENEX or others.

Remember to write your paper in a similar style as papers in the aforementioned conference proceedings, as unusual styles or formatting is the easiest way of getting (desk) rejected. Do a proper lit review first.

Comment: I appreciate your answer so much and just added the python code.

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt this is suitable for publication in Nature or Science.

Theoretical computer scientists will care about proofs of correctness and the best provable upper bound on the worst-case running time.  Until you have that, you don't have much, and it is unlikely that researchers will pay attention.

I don't believe your claim about "runtime ratio".  Surely that depends on the graph (or distribution on graphs), so if you give me a fixed ratio like 5 : 11 : 90, I simply do not believe it, and I will assume that you have misunderstood something.

You haven't defined what "transfers" are.

We're not a coding site, so we don't review code here.  Researchers will be interested in concise pseudocode and clear proofs of why it is correct.

Comment: Transfer number means edge number. I clarify that the runtime ratio is limited to the Python test case. I thought readers had knowledge about Bellman-Ford and SPFA. Therefore, I didn't explain it in detail.

Comment: @ShawxingKwok I hope you are aware that in graphs with many negative edges, SPFA tends to be slower than BF, hence you should be very explicit about your assumptions on the dataset.

Comment: @PålGD It's hard to avoid negative weight cycles in a set of simulated edges with massive negative weights. Could you give me some hints?